# Change Bootstrap popover arrow color with jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, popover

I am trying to change the arrow color of my Bootstrap popovers with jQuery (because regular css doesn't work).  This is my html code:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <span class="stat__title">1 Yr Target:</span>
        <small class="pop" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="POPOVER CONTENT">
            (?)
        </small>
        <br>
        <span class="stat__text">PLACEHOLDER</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="stat__title">EPS (ttm):</span>
        <br>
        <span class="stat__text">{{ riskStats?.quote?.eps }}</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is my TypeScript code (using Angular2):

```
export class DetailComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
    constructor(...) {
        this.activateToolTips();
    }

    ngAfterViewChecked() {
        this.formatToolTips();
    }

    activateToolTips() {
        jQuery('.pop').popover({ html : true, trigger: 'hover', container: 'body' });
    }

    formatToolTips() {
        jQuery('.popover').css({'color': '#506a85', 'font-weight': 'bold', 'background-color': 'red'});
        jQuery('.popover.right .arrow:after').css({'border-right-color': 'red'});
    }
}
```

The body of my popover turns red but the arrow doesn't change.  Any help on making this work is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> You can't manipulate :after, because it's not technically part of the DOM and therefore is inaccessible by any JavaScript. But you can add a new class with a new :after specified.

For example:

```
formatToolTips() {
  jQuery('.popover').css({'color': '#506a85', 'font-weight': 'bold', 'background-color': 'red'}).addClass('popover-my-arrow');
}
```

```
.popover-my-arrow > .arrow:after {
  border-right-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input, unfortunately that doesnt work tho

Answer (score 0):

I have included a sample using CSS

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.popover.right .arrow:after {
  border-right-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Popover Example</h3>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">Toggle popover</a>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the advice but Im not having any luck with that

Comment: thanks for the demo man, unfortunately it still isnt working, I think it might be an Angular 2 thing..